# Как выровнять отступы Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Делаю плеер на андроид. Дана следующая разметка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть одно Activity состоящая из двух трех фрагментов:

1. Основной фрагмент вместе со скроллом.
2. Плавающий фрагмент (Превью плеера. Этот блок появляется только если играет трек)
3. Навигационное меню, типа как в инстаграмме.

   P.S Плавающий фрагмент и меню находятся всегда внизу! (`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`)

Вопрос: Если плеер не играет, значит плавающий фрагмент отсутсвует и его заполняет основной фрагмент. 
Метод `layout.setPadding(0,0,0,125);` работает паршиво. На разных устройствах отступы могут быть в пол экрана. Как выровнять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы устанавливаете значение отступа == 125, но на разных  экранах разная плотность попробуйте конвертировать значение отступа для соответствующей плотности экрана:

```
/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 *
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into dp
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi /160f);
    return dp;
}
```